# How to move cursor to the beginning of the current line in UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, cursor-position, text-cursor

I want to have an insert tab button for my UITextView so that users be able to  insert a tab at beginning of the current line.
No matter where the cursor is in the line, the tab should be inserted at the beginning of the line, and after that the cursor must go to the end of the line.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Current line, or current paragraph? The latter is pretty easy, the former not so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no luck with `positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset:` and `characterRangeByExtendingPosition:inDirection:`.

But this works fine for me:

```
UITextRange *range = [textView selectedTextRange];
CGRect rect = [textView caretRectForPosition:range.start];
UITextPosition *start = [textView closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(0, rect.origin.y)];
[textView setSelectedTextRange:[textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:start]];
```

**UPD:** the code above is tested on iOS7 and earlier. And can no longer work with iOS9. Actually, I have some bugs in my text-editing app running on iOS9-devices. I'll update my answer after fixing my app.

Comment: This code does not go to the beginning of current line, but it puts the cursor at the beginning of the previous line.

Comment: have a look at the 3rd line.  this code will do the previous line.  You have to add the height of the rect as well to get the next line.
```UITextPosition *start = [textView closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(0, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height)];```

Comment: @horseshoe7, yeah that possible. The code above written for iOS7 (or maybe even iOS6). And UITextView changed in iOS8, iOS9. I'll update the answer later. Need to check new behavior first.

Answer (score 2):

UITextView implements the UITextInput protocol, which has a whole bunch of methods for determining positions of text. I'm not sure about this, but perhaps you can call:

1. `selectedTextRange` to get the caret position.
2. `positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset:` with `UITextLayoutDirectionLeft` to find the range to the start of the current line. (This I'm not sure about; maybe `characterRangeByExtendingPosition:inDirection:` would work better?)
3. Use `textRangeFromPosition:toPosition:` to get a range for the start of the lin.
4. Use `replaceRange:withText:` to insert a tab.

There might be other methods in that protocol that would let you figure that out if that doesn't work.

Edit: Seems that UITextView only implements UITextInput as of iOS 5. If you're targeting before that, I'm not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add the code that I've been using to move the cursor to the beginning of the line (`homeTap`) as it addresses some of the comments within @zxcat's answer, regarding the cursor being moved to the beginning of *previous* line rather than the current line:

```
- (void)homeTap:(id)s {
    UITextRange* range = [_textView selectedTextRange];
    CGRect rect = [_textView caretRectForPosition:range.start];
    float halfLineHeight = _textView.font.lineHeight / 2.0;
    UITextPosition* start = [_textView closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(0, rect.origin.y + halfLineHeight)];
    [_textView setSelectedTextRange:[_textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:start]];
}
```

Specifically, I add `halfLineHeight` to `rect.origin.y` to make sure the result from `closestPositionToPoint` is for the current line.